# Will my universal app get rejected if I don't create separate xibs for both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The app will be primarily for the iPhone but I would like the option of deploying to the iPad also (without having to do extra work!).

Will the app get rejected if the dimensions of the iPad version are the same as for the iPhone, i.e if I don't change anything in terms of resources and view controllers etc. but just specify that the application runs on both iPhone and iPad?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A universal app is different from an iPhone app that runs on an iPad. If you compile it only as an iPhone app, it can be loaded onto an iPad and viewed in native iPhone window dimensions centered on the screen or scaled bigger by a factor of two, still centered on the screen.

But if you compiled it as a universal app, then your window on the iPad is bigger. If all of your other views are the same views that the iPhone uses, they will all occupy the upper left corner of the screen that corresponds to the iPhone Widow frame. That would look odd, and it would deprive the user of scaling it bigger.

I suggest you don't compile as a universal app; only compile as an iPhone app. (I suspect that you are already doing this. You just shouldn't refer to it as a universal app.)

Comment: Thanks! If I build as an iPhone App, will images with iPad specific naming conventions i.e. launch images get used when the app is launched from an iPad?

Comment: I would have to check this when I get back to my computer, but if you are compiling for only the iPhone, I don't think you will have the option to specify launch images for the iPad. Maybe someone else can give you a quicker answer to that question.

Answer (score 3):

I recenty put a Universal App in the Store that contains only xib's designed for iPhone.  There were no submission problems, though it still is a pain to make icons of different sizes.  Make sure your auto-resizing masks are correct and it may still look fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's not considered a universal app unless you specify for both iphone and ipad. I think you will get rejected. iPhone apps will run on iPads though, just at the dimensions of the iphone by default.

Run your app on the iPad simulator and see what I mean. Users can double (2x) the size but that doesn't change resolution.

Answer (score 1):

All iPhone apps will automatically run on iPad inside an emulator that basically does exactly what you describe: run the app with the dimensions and code as on the phone.

If that's your goal, do nothing and let the emulator do your work for you.